# Lua Parse After Match

Tags: string, parsing, lua

Using Lua 5.3 I'm trying to parse a string that looks something like.

```
a=data0
b=data
c=data
a=data1
b=data
c=data
a=data2
...
```

I want to parse the 'b=data & c=data' after the occurrence of 'a=data1'. I know I can start by doing `string.find(exampleString, 'a=data1')` which will give me the start/end position and I know where to start parsing for b after that but I don't know how long 'data' will be after that, so I don't know where to start for parsing 'c'? Is there anyway I can just do a parse next line type of thing? How else should I tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> know where to start parsing for b after that but I don't know how long 'data' will be after that, so I don't know where to start for parsing 'c'? **Is there anyway I can just do a parse next line type of thing?**

Yes, just can just match to the EOL character:

```
for letter, data in s:gmatch('(%w)=(.-)\n') do
    print(letter,data)
end
```

`.-` = 0 or more characters, as few as possible
`\n` = EOL character
The parentheses capture parts of the pattern we want gmatch to return.

You could also say `([^\n]*)` which means 0 or more character which are *not* a newline.